# Wrangling Input Validation Tooltip, issues in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, validation, webkit

I have been trying to find a way to wrangle the HTML input validation tooltip and can't for the life of me find a solution that works across Chromium and Webkit browsers. I understand that Chromium specifically follows the spec to the letter but the user experience is awful and I cannot figure out a way around it.

What I am trying to achieve is that `onblur` the input gets `validity.valid` and if invalid we call `reportValidity()` which displays the validation tooltip. I am using the title element to then fill the tooltip text. The problem arises when we call `reportValidity()` which then pulls the input back into focus putting you in a loop where you can never leave the input. If you try `blur()` on the element after `reportValidity()` then Safari goes into a weird loop that nearly crashes the browser. However Firefox handles nearly all cases gracefully.

I am being pushed to the point where I feel like I will need to implement my own validation tooltip system, but I am really trying to wrangle the HTML input validation tooltip instead. Any ideas for a cross-browser solution?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)